# Can't add tab bar to iPad app using storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6

I have an iPad app using a tableview/details configuration. I want to embed this in a tab bar controller. I am following several tutorials to add a tab bar controller in storyboard, but my results are not the same as in the tutorial:

1. I am not given the first tab bar item to edit; neither in the storyboard nor in the file tree.
2. My segue icon between the tab bar controller and the navigation controller is a slanted icon, not the horizontal segue icon I see in the tutorial.
3. The new tab bar does not appear at the bottom of my table view.

Please, what am I missing? (I wish I could post a screen shot, but alas I don't have the reputation!)

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Newbie error on my part. I was trying to add a tab bar item to the tab bar controller. Now it's clear: I edit the tab bar items on the respective view controllers. The YouTube below was helpful also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a video from YouTube that explains it. It's pretty straightforward.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFTcR9H-OYQ